# After updating to latest AMD driver can't login Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm Windows user since forever 
I installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 5 days ago and I installed latest AMD driver after restarting I couldn't login I was stuck in the login screen.
I uninstalled amdgpu driver so I could login.

Answer (score 0):

There was an advisory on the AMD site stating AMDGPU-PRO 17.30 was not compatible with 16.04.3 with the new HWE stack (kernel and Xorg).  As far as I can tell, since yesterday the advisory has disappeared from the AMD site and there is possibly a new 17.30 build that supports 16.04.3.  I am yet to try it.

Comment: Any progress so far? I can't get it to work :(

Comment: Turns out despite the errors setup gave me, it did install amd driver! I was wondering how my pc got suddenly so much faster although driver setup returned error :)